# Django Admin urls

Tags: django, django-admin

I would like to use administration website directly by reverse url in my Django application but I get this error : `No module named admin.site.urls`

I have urls.py file which looks like :

```
import os
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

from BirthCertificate import views
from Identity import views
from Accueil import views
from log import views
from Mairie import views
from Table import views
from Recensement import views
from Configurations import views
from Mariage import views

import debug_toolbar

from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name=os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, 'Accueil/templates/Choice.html')),
        name='choice'),
    url(r'^admin/', include('admin.site.urls')),
    url(r'^BirthCertificate/', include('BirthCertificate.urls')),
    url(r'^Identity/', include('Identity.urls')),
    url(r'^Accueil/', include('Accueil.urls')),
    url(r'^Home/', include('log.urls')),
    url(r'^Mairie/', include('Mairie.urls')), 
    url(r'^Table/', include('Table.urls')), 
    url(r'^Recensement/', include('Recensement.urls')),
    url(r'^Configurations/', include('Configurations.urls')),
    url(r'^__debug__/', include(debug_toolbar.urls)),
    url(r'^Mariage/', include('Mariage.urls')),
]
```

And one of my HTML template has :

```
{% if request.user|has_group:"admin" %}
    <li><a href="{% url "admin" %}" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> Administration </a></li>
{% endif %}
```

Something is wrong ? 
I don't find How I can solve this error ..

Answer (score 45, accepted):

[In Django 1.9+](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#hooking-adminsite-instances-into-your-urlconf), you don't need to use `include`. Use the callable `admin.site.urls`, not the string `'admin.site.urls'`.

```
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
```

[In Django 2.0+](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#hooking-adminsite-instances-into-your-urlconf), you can use `path()` instead of `url()`.

```
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
```

[In Django < 1.9](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#hooking-adminsite-instances-into-your-urlconf) you pass `admin.site.urls` to `include`.

```
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
```

To reverse the admin index url, change the url tag in your template to:

```
{% url "admin:index" %}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I get this error : `Reverse for 'admin' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []` I would like to access directly to django administration page with url in my template, is it possible ?

Comment: That's because `admin` is just the namespace. You need to include the name of the url pattern as well, e.g. `{% url "admin:index" %}` for the admin index.

Comment: I'm in the process of upgrading an app from Django 1.11 to 4.0.3, and the variant that seems to work for me is this: `re_path(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls)`.

Comment: @GrahamKlyne yes, `re_path()` will work, but so should the `path()` line from my answer, which is [what the docs suggest](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/admin/#hooking-adminsite-instances-into-your-urlconf)