# django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: 'admin' is not a registered namespace

Tags: django

I have a Django projects with two apps, "projects" and "codebox", they were running fine, then at some point I got the following error:

> django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: 'admin' is not a registered
>   namespace

If I remove the link to my admin panel from my template this error goes away, but then I can't get to my admin panel:

```
<a href="{% url "admin:index" %}">Admin</a>
```

I was working in the urls.py files when this error occurred, have I changed something that is inadvertently having an impact on the admin link?

Here is my top level urls.py file:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path, re_path

urlpatterns = [
    # path('', include('projects.urls')),
    path('projects/', include('projects.urls')),
    re_path('^accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    re_path('^logged_out/', include('projects.urls')),
    path('codebox/', include('codebox.urls')),
]
```

Here is my urls.py for "projects":

```
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views
app_name = 'projects'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    path('<int:pk>/', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    path('insight/', views.InsightView.as_view(), name='insight'),
    path('logged_out/', views.LoggedoutView.as_view(), name='loggedout'),
    path('insight/subgen/', views.SubgenView.as_view(), name='subgen'),
]
```

And here is urls.py for my second app, codebox:

```
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views
app_name = 'codebox'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    path('<int:pk>/', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    path('form/', views.CreateView, name="form"),
]
```

Comment: Was the link working beforehand? Did you rename the `app_name` of `projects` from `admin`? I don't see where you include the admin URLs in your URL config files. You're importing `admin` in your top-level `urls.py` but not using it. Did you perhaps mean to include it like so: `path('admin/', admin.site.urls),`?

Comment: Doh, thank you, I must have removed that line by mistake when working on the file!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django Admin urls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44130643/django-admin-urls)

Answer (score 0):

add this in top of project/urls.py

```py
from django.conf.urls import include, url
```

then add this in the `url_pattern`

```py
url(r' ', include(('<app_name>.urls','<app_name>'), namespace='<app_name>')),
```

hope this will work

Answer (score -1):

Check your base html file which you're extending to other html pages. If there is some space between urls tag remove that space and save your file and try again you can check below code for ref.

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from passapp import views
urlpatterns = [
path('', views.index, name='index'),
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('passapp/', include('passapp.urls')),
]

href="{% url 'admin:index' %}"
```